# In cakephp my jquery $.ajax() call is not calling an action from another controller when explicitly told to do so

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

After having tried to make this work for three days now I'm posting this on stackoverflow.

I have a controller for messages and a controller for links in my cakephp application. I cannot figure out why a $.ajax() will call the correct action from within the messages controller but doesn't seem to even try to go to the one specified by ajax call.

this will work and will actually call my add action in my messages controller:

```
    $('#add_message').click( function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/messages/add",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {
                text: $('#message_text').val(),
                group_id: $('#group_id').val()                  
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $('#message_list').prepend(
                        $(jqXHR.responseText).hide().fadeIn('slow')
                );
                $('#message_text').val("");

            }   
        });
```

the code below doesn't even go to the right url as specified by the ajax call('/links/add' corresponding to the links controller's add action) instead it uses the  url that renders the current view (in this case /messages/index). A jqueryui dialog is displayed for user data entry when submitted it alerts 'success' so the function is being triggered.

I used chrome developer tools to examine the headers it never attempts to call the url /links/add.

```
$( "#dialog-add_group_link" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add Link": function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        Url: "/links/add/",
                        data: {
                            tags: $('#link_tags').val(),
                            text: $('#text').val(),
                            href: $('#href').val(),
                            group_id: $('#group_id').val()
                        },  
                        success: function() {
                            alert('success');
                        }
                    });
                    $( this ).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            close: function() {

            }
        });
```

Is there something I'm missing that is telling it to use a different URL? I'm not sure why this won't call the /links/add action and I have tried making the link an absolute link so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The `url` field must be lower-case

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. I got so caught up in the problem I neglected to look at the case. Thank you sometimes all you need is a second pair of eyes.